# Compilation error is showing while splitting 1 column into multiple column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

While splitting my one column in dataFrame  into 2 column using below code, I have tried with two type of code but both the time I got error while running the program.in IteliJ screen its not showing error(means no red mark) but while running it shows error on console.
my data frame is:
+---------+
|Wrap Time|
+---------+
|   19.674|
|   11.466|
|  263.697|

code: 1

```
val df2=  df.withColumn("nested", split(col("Wrap Time"), "."))
      .withColumn("Call Completion Code_1", $"nested".getItem(0))
      .withColumn("Call Completion Code_2", $"nested".getItem(1))
      .withColumn("Call Completion Code_3", $"nested".getItem(2))
      .drop("nested")
```

Error:(26, 43) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR]
   val df2=  df.withColumn("nested", split(col("Wrap Time"), "."))

Error:(26, 43) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR])VR in trait UFunc.
Unspecified value parameter impl.
   val df2=  df.withColumn("nested", split(col("Wrap Time"), "."))

code: 2:

```
val df2= df.
      withColumn("nested", split($"Wrap Time", ".")).select($"nested"(0) as "Call Completion Code_1", $"nested"(1) as "Call Completion Code_2")
```

Error:(23, 33) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName,String,VR]
      withColumn("nested", split($"Wrap Time", ".")).select($"nested"(0) as "Call Completion Code_1", $"nested"(1) as "Call Completion Code_2")

Error:(23, 33) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName,String,VR])VR in trait UFunc.
Unspecified value parameter impl.
      withColumn("nested", split($"Wrap Time", ".")).select($"nested"(0) as "Call Completion Code_1", $"nested"(1) as "Call Completion Code_2")

spark version is: spark-2.3.2
scala 2.11.8
jdk1.8.0_20
sbt-1.2.7

Comment: my data frame is: 

Wrap Time
 19.674
 11.466
 263.697

expected result:

Wrap Time1 Wrap Time2 
 19        674
 11        466
 263       697

Comment: AKIAIZEQNOUXF3VTHHVQ1 1t4SKEV5sZQ+LRV4KYCS6496FeHR3tes9hWrKl66t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below code. It should work.

val df2=df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"WRAP", "\\."))
.select(
  $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2")
)

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but tried with ur code

But got the same error


Error:(50, 48) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName,String,VR]
    val df2=call_Rawdf.withColumn("_tmp", split($"Wrap Time", "\\.")) .select( $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"), $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2") )



I have imported import breeze.linalg.split for using  "Split" function

can u please let me know which jar file imported for using  "Split" function

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem. Intellij suggest breeze but split in breeze doesn't work
plz remove breeze just import this line. Sql functions

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, array, explode, col,split}`